Question on Complex Integral with Polar Form
Let $f$ be a complex-valued integrable function. Write the complex number $\int fd\mu$ in its polar form, letting $w$ be a complex number of absolute value 1 such that
\begin{align}
\int fd\mu = w\left|\int fd\mu\right|.
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
\left|\int fd\mu\right| = w^{-1}\int fd\mu = \int(w^{-1}f)d\mu = \int\mathfrak{R}(w^{-1}f)d\mu \leq \int |f|d\mu.
\end{align}
I have difficulty understanding why $\int(w^{-1}f)d\mu = \int\mathfrak{R}(w^{-1}f)d\mu$ is true. Could someone please help me out? Thanks a lot in advance!
I want to write $f=u+iv$ and $w=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$. Then $w^{-1} = \cos\theta-i\sin\theta$ and
\begin{align}
w^{-1}f = (u\cos\theta+v\sin\theta)+i(v\cos\theta-u\sin\theta).
\end{align}
I couldn't see why $\mathfrak{I}(w^{-1}f) = v\cos\theta-u\sin\theta = 0$.

Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. A complex-valued function $f$ on $X$ is integrable if its real and imaginary parts $\mathfrak{R}(f)$ and $\mathfrak{I}(f)$ are integrable; if $f$ is integrable, then its integral is defined by
\begin{align*}
    \int fd\mu = \int\mathfrak{R}(f)d\mu + i\int\mathfrak{I}(f)d\mu.
\end{align*}

I can see that $|\int fd\mu|$ is real, so there shouldn't be an imaginary part in $\int(w^{-1}f)d\mu$. But I want a derivation.

Hint: $\int(w^{-1}f)d\mu$ is real.

@KurtG. As I mentioned in the above comment, I can see that $\int(w^{-1}f)d\mu=|\int fd\mu|$ which is real. But I want to see a mathematical derivation that shows the imaginary part of $\int(w^{-1}f)d\mu=0$.

Hint II. Combine that knowledge with the last formula in your question.

@KurtG. I don't know if you got my point, and neither do I know if I got your point. What I meant is that since $\int(w^{1}f)d\mu$ is real, the imaginary part of it has to be zero; for otherwise there would be a contradiction. But this is from "logic", not "derivation". I want to see how one could "derive" it using "equations" or "inequalities" so to speak.

Since real numbers form a field, any difference of two real numbers is a real number. Put $x=\int(w^{-1}f)d\mu$. Then, $iIm(x)=x-Re(x)$. RHS is real, so $(x-Re(x))^2\geq 0$. On the other hand, $(iIm(x))^2=-Im^2(x) \le 0$. So, LHS=RHS=0.

I got your point and you are overthinking this. Plug instead of $f$ into the last formula of your post the function $w^{-1}f$ and use that the integral is real. See @kakashi's answer for the spoiler.

Perhaps a bit cleaner: \begin{align*}
\int w^{-1}fd\mu = \int\mathfrak{R}(w^{-1}f)d\mu + i\int\mathfrak{I}(w^{-1}f)d\mu.
\end{align*} is real. Therefore the expression $i\int\mathfrak{I}(w^{-1}f)d\mu$ is zero.

$|\int f| = \int w^{-1}f$ is a real number, so $\int w^{-1}f = \Re(\int w^{-1}f) = \int \Re(w^{-1}f)$.

Note that the polar form $re^{i \pi \theta}$ ensure $e^{i \pi \theta}$ is on the unit circle. This means $r=\vert \int f d\mu\vert$ and $w=e^{i \pi \theta}$ so it's just the polar form of $\int f d\mu$ in disguise. We can also see that $w^{-1} = e^{-i \pi \theta}$ which gives $$w^{-1} \int f d\mu = w^{-i \pi \theta}rw^{i \pi \theta} = r$$
which is a direct consequence of how $w$ was chosen. If you want to use the trigonometric form write it as $$\int f d\mu = rw  = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$$
and then using $w^{-1} = \cos \theta - i \sin \theta$ gives us $$w^{-1}\int f d \mu = (\cos \theta - i\sin \theta) r(cos \theta + i\sin \theta) = r(cos^2\theta + \sin^2 \theta) = r$$
